# Multiple Files running in Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

**Please forgive me if this seems dumb or anything, I've tried looking places, and I don't know if this is the correct place to put it or anything**

So I am trying to make a discord bot, and I have a script and everything, but The thing is, I only have one script. I don't know how to use other scripts, but I think I am not the only one who has had this problem because If someone were to use two languages, then it would require two files, but I don't know how to make the second file run.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: In Node.js, you just use some type of `require('<package>')` statement - is this what you're talking about? Do you know much about Node.js?

Comment: Hey guys! I do not know much about node.js,

Comment: I am just getting started with it

As for an example
If I have a script "index" that has all the commands of like ping and stuff, to handle that stuff, But then I want another script to handle all the admin commands and stuff, but When I attempted this, only the Index script worked, not the AdminCommands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, this is as good a spot as any to post this question. Basically what you'll need to do, is something like this:

In a separate file where you want to store your admin commands (I named this file `adminCmds.js`), set up a `module.exports` variable that points to an object with your admin commands. In my example, my `adminCmds.js` file is in the same directory as `index.js`.

Try something like this:

```
// inside adminCmds.js
function admin1() {
    console.log('in admin 1 command');
    // your command code here
}

function admin2() {
    console.log('in admin 2 command');
    // your command code here
}

module.exports = {
    checkAdminCmd: function(message) {
        let command = message.content, found = false;

        switch(command) {
            // your first admin command (can be whatever you want)
            case '?admin1':
                // set found equal to true so your index.js file knows
                //   to not try executing 'other' commands
                found = true;
                // execute function associated with this command
                admin1();
                break;

            // your second admin command (similar setup as above)
            case '?admin2':
                found = true;
                admin2();
                break;

            // ... more admin commands
        }

        // value of 'found' will be returned in index.js
        return found;
    }
};
```

In your main `index.js` file, set up your main message listener like this:

```
// get admin commands from other file
const adminCmds = require('./adminCmds');

// set message listener 
client.on('message', message => {
    let command = message.content;

    // execute admin commands
    // -> if function checkAdminCmd returns false, move on to checking 'other' commands
    if ( adminCmds.checkAdminCmd(message) )
        return;

    // execute other commands
    else {
        switch(command) {
            case '?PING':
                message.reply('pong');
                break;

            // ... other commands here
        }
    }
});
```

I'd highly recommend looking at some Node.js tutorials before using Discord.js - it'll help out a lot. But if you run into any troubles in the meantime, I'd be glad to try to help.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial recommendations ? :D P.s. thank you , this worked :D

Comment: @Jeffeeze - yes! I would highly recommend this one by The Net Ninja: [Node Js for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-7RQ46RgxU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp)

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks so much :D